# Help identifying a night-scented, red flowered, ornamental shrub growing in Madeira

Tags: identification

A neighbour found this shrub growing in gardens in Madeira and described it as highly scented at night. My first thoughts were *Plumeria cvs* but the long throat to the flower isn't right and the petals aren't folded as neatly.

[image: general habit]
[image: close-up of leaves and flowers]

Comment: Combretum indicum

Comment: @Maria you're right, please add an answer so I can accept it.